# Should I always encode my data in utf-8 before using preg_match in php 5.4?

Tags: php, regex, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to use preg_match() on my data which is encoded in ISO-8859-1. If I try to match a string which has non UTF-8 characters in it preg_match() gives me an empty matches array.

Consider the following code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.iso-8859-1');
mb_internal_encoding("iso-8859-1");

// this returns an empty $matches array
$str = "Prices starting at " . chr(0x80);
preg_match('/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,3}/u', $str, $matches);

// this returns a filled matches array
$str = "Prices starting at $";
preg_match('/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,3}/u', $str, $matches);
```

The chr(0x80) is the euro sign in this case.
Before I upgraded to php 5.4 this worked fine, but since php 5.4 not anymore.

Is there any way to make php 5.4 preg_match() understand my ISO-8859-1 data?

Comment: `/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,3}/u` the u stands for unicode, have you tried `/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,3}/`?

Comment: Nope. This particular line belongs to a class in the Kohana framework.   I won't be looking into this any further: converting our data to utf-8 seems a better solution.